# How to access individual columns in a table collection with mixed cell widths

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table with 5 columns.
Only the first row has 4 columns, the first row first column is merged.
I want to delete the 4th column of each row. But because of the mixed cell widths I receive run time error 5992.

looked at this solution:
[How to access columns in a table that have different cell widths from MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399061/how-to-access-columns-in-a-table-that-have-different-cell-widths-from-ms-word)

The code is not for VBA

Comment: *"I want to delete the 4th column of each row"* - Wouldn't that be the same as just deleting the 4th column?

Comment: Please update your question with your existing code and if possible a screenshot of the table layout.

Comment: That not-VBA code isn't VBA indeed, but shouldn't be too hard to translate since it's using the same object model. What have you tried? Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: This seems to be the solution , But I don't know how to code this in VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316722/deleting-columns-from-a-table-with-merged-cells?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Long
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
    With .Rows(r)
      If .Cells.Count > 3 Then .Cells(4).Delete
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes!!!! PERFECT, when you have time, maybe you can help me to understand how you got around the mixed cell width errors

Comment: The macro tests each row; it doesn't do column-wise processing. The line If .Cells.Count > 3 Then .Cells(4).Delete tests whether there are at least 4 cells on a given row and, if so, deletes the 4th cell from that row.